# Drupal 7 : bind two or more taxonomies

Tags: drupal-7, taxonomy

I'm using drupal 7 to make a kind of humanities collaborative portal. 
Let's say I have 3 taxonomies : **authors**, *concepts*, dissertation and the corresponding content-types.
I would like to bind the terms in these taxonomies together. 
If I write a dissertation, I would like to be able to choose at least one couple of author-concept as though it was one new tag. 
For example, I wrote a dissertation about "What is the self ?", and used **Husserl**'s *cogito* on one hand and **Hume**'s *self* on the other hand.

I'm coding my own search engine to fetch these couples so that if I search "**Hume** *cogito*" my dissertation won't be in the results.

My problem is that I don't know how to bind taxonomies in that way nor linking those taxonomies when the user creates a content. 
I thought about hierachical taxonomy but it doesn't seem to make sense.
Any idea welcome !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our Project we were using a similar functionality for glossary search.
There are 2 methods one is
 Create a content-type for Items.
   1)Any term can be mapped to multiple other terms by creating two fields of term reference and making the second field with add many(1 term -may terms relationship) .

2)There was a module in drupal 6 called "**Term Relations**" which i believe has dev version for drupal 7

Comment: I'm trying term relations : it seems quite powerful. Otherwise, I'll try the first but I think it's a little bit dirty. Thanks :)